# Sanitizing php ldap bind data

Tags: php, ldap, sanitization

I have a form, that collects login and password informations, used to authenticate user against MS AD LDAP. Nothing special. Just username and pass. But i'm wondering how to sanitize user provided data. Chence username is not very complicated (most of special chars can be disallowed), the problem still exists with password, which can contain any char and I cannot use strip_tags (maybe someone pass includes a special chars or a string looking like a tag). What are the security risks in this case? How to make this bind method safe?
Sorry for my horrible English and thanks for all replies
Smok.

Comment: When your password is encrypted/hashed it's no longer a problem? You shouldn't be saving plain text passwords anyway?

Comment: PHP's ldap_bind function uses pain text password to bind user. I do not know any way to send an encrypted pass to this function.